# AltBeacon onBeaconServiceConnect not called

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, altbeacon

I stuck implementing simple Beacon monitor with AltBeacon library using its examples. In short:
I took its [reference application](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference), [downloaded](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/download.html) and integrated its latest build and run app on my Samsung Galaxy S2 with CM (Android 4.4.4). I see that onBeaconServiceConnect callback never called, though bindService is called. I believe onBeaconServiceConnect should be called in order application to work correctly.

I've tried to set beaconManager.debug = true; but it didn't show me any new logs (maybe because I'm using precompiled libraries from site).

Also I've checked if the problem with my firmware/hardware - but I see it's able to monitor beacons with other applications from Google Play. I have iPhone and MacBook and one more android device so I can simulate any transmitting signal which is needed to let AltBeacon catch it.

Can someone help me? I would appreciate any clue you give me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A failure to receive a callback to `onBeaconServiceConnect` is usually caused by an incorrect `AndroidManifest.xml` setup to declare the `BeaconService`.  The library uses manifest merging to automatically merge these definitions into your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` from the library's `AndroidManifest.xml` at compile time.  If manifest merging is not enabled, the service will never be declared and the app will not get the `onBeaconServiceConnect` callback.

If using Eclipse, check your project.properties file and make sure it has the line: `manifestmerger.enabled=true`.

If this does not solve your problem, please post the code that binds to the `BeaconService` and let us know the IDE you are using.

Comment: Yup you're right, just solved the problem by adding services declaration to manifest. 
I'm using Intelij IDEA don't know how to do automatic merging there. However adding following helps:
<service android:enabled="true"
                 android:exported="true"
                 android:isolatedProcess="false"
                 android:label="beacon"                 android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService">
        </service>

        <service android:enabled="true"                 android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor">
        </service>